# How to apply RANSAC on SURF, SIFT and ORB matching results

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction, orb, ransac, feature-descriptor

I'm working on image processing. I want to match 2D Features and I did many tests on SURF, SIFT, ORB.
How can I apply RANSAC on SURF/SIFT/ORB in OpenCV?

Answer (score 24):

OpenCV has the function `cv::findHomography` which can optionally use RANSAC to find the homography matrix relating two images. You can see an example of this function in action [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html).

Specifically the section of code you are interested in is:

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
```

You can then use the function `cv::perspectiveTransform` to warp the images according to the homography matrix.

Other options for `cv::findHomography` other than `CV_RANSAC` are `0` which uses every point and `CV_LMEDS` which uses the Least-Median method. More info can be found in the OpenCV camera calibration documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the python implementation of applying `ransac` using `skimage` either with `ProjectiveTransform` or `AffineTransform` (i.e. Homography) model on obtained SIFT / SURF keypoints. This implementation first does Lowe's ratio test on obtained keypoints then it does ransac on filtered keypoints from Lowe's ratio test.

```
import cv2
from skimage.measure import ransac
from skimage.transform import ProjectiveTransform, AffineTransform
import numpy as np


def siftMatching(img1, img2):
    # Input : image1 and image2 in opencv format
    # Output : corresponding keypoints for source and target images
    # Output Format : Numpy matrix of shape: [No. of Correspondences X 2] 

    surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(100)
    # surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

    kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

    # Lowe's Ratio test
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1, 2)

    # Ransac
    model, inliers = ransac(
            (src_pts, dst_pts),
            AffineTransform, min_samples=4,
            residual_threshold=8, max_trials=10000
        )

    n_inliers = np.sum(inliers)

    inlier_keypoints_left = [cv2.KeyPoint(point[0], point[1], 1) for point in src_pts[inliers]]
    inlier_keypoints_right = [cv2.KeyPoint(point[0], point[1], 1) for point in dst_pts[inliers]]
    placeholder_matches = [cv2.DMatch(idx, idx, 1) for idx in range(n_inliers)]
    image3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, inlier_keypoints_left, img2, inlier_keypoints_right, placeholder_matches, None)

    cv2.imshow('Matches', image3)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    src_pts = np.float32([ inlier_keypoints_left[m.queryIdx].pt for m in placeholder_matches ]).reshape(-1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ inlier_keypoints_right[m.trainIdx].pt for m in placeholder_matches ]).reshape(-1, 2)

    return src_pts, dst_pts
```